# What is the difference between saveNodeCoors and \psGetNodeCenter?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,3)
\rput(1.5,0.5){\trinode{CN}{NodeA}}
\rput(3.5,2.5){\trinode{EN}{NodeB}}
\pnode(! \psGetNodeCenter{CN} CN.x 2 add CN.y 1 add ){MyCNode}
\ncline[linecolor=red]{MyCNode}{EN}
\ncline[linecolor=blue]{CN}{EN}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the **image**, I don't think that the coordinate of MyCNode is (3.5,1.5 !?)

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,saveNodeCoors](5,3)
\rput(1.5,0.5){\trinode{CN}{NodeA}}
\rput(3.5,2.5){\trinode{EN}{NodeB}}
\pnode(! N-CN.x 2 add N-CN.y 1 add ){MyCNode}
\ncline[linecolor=red]{MyCNode}{EN}
\ncline[linecolor=blue]{CN}{EN}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the above code, so (N-CN.x,N-CN.y)=(0,0) !?

P\S: In pst-node documentation, there is a sentence which has the following content: *In the following example it doesn’t work because the relative node setting via \rput is not taken into account.* Truly, I do not understand it clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit tricky: The "vertical center" of the triangle is placed at the position of `\rput`. But the node itself is the center of the *Text*!!

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](5,3)
    \rput(0,0){\trinode{A}{A}}\psdot(A)%
    \rput(1.5,0.5){\trinode{CN}{NodeA}}\psdot(CN)%
    \rput(3.5,2.5){\trinode{EN}{NodeB}}\psdot(EN)%
    \pnode(! \psGetNodeCenter{CN} CN.x 2 add CN.y 1 add ){MyCNode}\psdot(MyCNode)
    \ncline[linecolor=red]{MyCNode}{EN}
    \ncline[linecolor=blue]{CN}{EN}
    \end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,saveNodeCoors](-1,-1)(5,3)
\rput(0,0){\trinode{A}{NodeA}}\psdot(A)
\rput(1.5,0.5){\trinode{CN}{NodeA}}\psdot(CN)
\rput(3.5,2.5){\trinode{EN}{NodeB}}\psdot(EN)
\psdot[linecolor=red](! N-CN.x N-CN.y)
\pnode(! N-CN.x 2 add N-CN.y 1 add ){MyCNode}\psdot(MyCNode)
\ncline[linecolor=red]{MyCNode}{EN}
\ncline[linecolor=blue]{CN}{EN}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Using the save node coordinates makes only real sense for nodes defined by `\pnode`

Comment: Yes, I see. And with the second question,  (N-CN.x,N-CN.y)=(0,0) is set by default !?. ( the coordinates of \rput are not loaded within saveNodeCoors ).

Comment: For nodes which have a contents (box) it makes no sense to use the internal variables `N-??.x, N-??.y`. Use it only for nodes where you explicitly set the node center: `\pnode`, `\cnode`, ...